# Find the power series solution about $0$ for $(x+3)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(x+2)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the power series solution about $0$ for the differential equation $$(x+3)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(x+2)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0.$$

My attempt:

Let the solution be of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n.$

We have, $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}$$ and  $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}.$$

Substituting these values in the given equation we have,

$$(x+3)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(x+2)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\\(x+3)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}+(x+2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n=0.$$

We proceed to simplify this, as
$$\begin{align*}
(x+3)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}+(x+2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-1}+3\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n+1)c_{n+1}x^{n}+3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)c_{n+1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n&=0\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[n(n+1)c_{n+1}+3(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+nc_n+2(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_n]x^n+6c_2+2c_1+c_0&=0
\end{align*}$$

Thus we can say,
$$6c_2+2c_1+c_0=0,$$ and $$n(n+1)c_{n+1}+3(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+nc_n+2(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_n=0$$ for $n\geq 1.$

But I don't understand what to do next, for I am unable express each of the coefficient with the help of $c_0$ and $c_1.$

I think, this problem must have some initial value conditions. But it's missing in the excercise of the book (Please check out the reference below). I am afraid, but this appears confusing enough.

*For reference*- This problem is from the book "Differential Equations " (Third Edition) , by S.L Ross. It appears in Chapter - $VI$ in Section $6.1$ as an excercise in Problem -$10$, on page number $232.$

Comment: It looks good to me. You have a recurrence relation for the coefficients. To solve for them, you need the initial conditions.

Comment: @K.Jiang But no initial conditions are given. This problem is from the book "Differential Equations " by SL Ross, Ch-VI, problem -10.

Comment: try [this solution](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/may_17_2023.pdf) from the internet, solved in 2 ways: using Taylor series, and also using power series. This is possible because $x=0$ is ordinary point. Taylor series is easier, but need to do lots of derivatives, that is all.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, that was a great help indeed!

Comment: For what it’s worth, WA indicates that $y=e^{-x}(x+3)^2$ is one solution. Moreover, this appears to be the only solution for which $y\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$. (At the level of power series, one substitutes $y=e^{-x} z$ and verifies that $z=x^2+6x+9$ is the only terminating series solution.)